# Missing pins for some help pages on localized sites

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, help-center, russian-stackoverflow

On enSO there are pinned links at [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) (just showing part of them to demonstrate what I'm talking about).

[image: pinned links at help center]

But [on esSO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/) there are none of them.

[On ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/) only one is present (near Code of Conduct).

[ptSO help](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/) has most of them, but not all.

Only on [jaSO](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/) everything is OK.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some issues with the ability to pin articles on the Spanish SO site but that has been fixed.  There will pins on that site shortly. Furthermore, each community will have different pins available since the memberships assesses different articles with varying value.

Comment: As far as I see on English communities pinned articles are the same. Also I suppose that we should have the same rules and their importance and priority (I assume pins express this) for different communities. This would make more sense if we could have separate rules for every community.